# javascript save canvas(png) from IE

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

I used html2canvas library. I want to store the image using the html2canvas. I success to store image from html2canvas!!! WOW!!! but.... IE has failed... I want to store all of browser.

I find navigator.msSaveBlob... I was happy~  but the happiness did not last long... base64 Encording Image is String! but I want to store pngfile! help me!!!  (PS. I seriously want to slap a strong chest of IE)

~this is code~

```
html2canvas($("body")[0], {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var img2 = img.split("data:image/png;base64,")[1];



      //var blobObject = new Blob([img2],{type:"image/jpeg"});
        var blobObject = new Blob([img2]);
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blobObject, 'test.png'); // The user only has the option of clicking the Save button.
      alert('File save request made using msSaveBlob() - note the single "Save" button below.');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The sad answer is... :-((

Chrome & Firefox have supported `canvas.toBlob` for a while, but...

**IE & Edge don't yet natively support `canvas.toBlob`**

But there are nice polyfills that bring `.toBlob` to IE/Edge.

I like Eli Grey's [FileSaverJS](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) and his [canvas-toBlobJS](https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js).

BlueImp's [JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob)  is popular, too.

Comment: thanks!!! you are so best!! I resolve question from your reply~ thank you thank you

Comment: Is there any example to convert html2canvas?